# How can I reduce file names after Angular prod build

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli, config

After building Angular 8 project, I have a lot of files with too long names.

Can I configure my angular.json for reduce them?

[image]

Comment: Please post your `angular.json`, specifically `architect->build->configurations->production`.

Answer (score 1):

If it would be possible straight from angular.json it would be in the build section of the file.

I checked https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#build-target and its options and I don't think that it's possible.

What you'd need to do is to configure a custom webpack config.
https://alligator.io/angular/custom-webpack-config/